# Split on colons in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have a column in SQL table which would have data like this:

**"College: Queenstown College"** or **"University: University of Queensland"**

Text before the **":"** could be different. So, how can i select only the text before the **":"** from the column and text after the **":(space)"**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably consider putting your table into [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) rather than storing 2 pieces of data in the same column...

```
;with yourtable as
(
select 'College: Queenstown College' as col UNION ALL
select 'University: University of Queensland'
)
select 
     left(col,charindex(': ',col)-1) AS InstitutionType,
     substring(col, charindex(': ',col)+2, len(col)) AS InstitutionName
from yourtable
```

Comment: It's possible to get the text after the ":<space>"?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `charindex` and `substring` functions:

```
substring(theField, 1, charindex(':', theField) - 1)
```